# Sum of odd numbers x

Tags: summation

In the [link-'Exmpla 1'](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~ygongjun/nerzic/content/induction/second_principle.html) says that $1+3+5+...+(2n+1)=(n+1)^2$. Is it false? Actually, ıt should be  $1+3+5+...+(2n-1)=n^2$,shouln't it?

Comment: Try your formula for the value of $n+1$ instead of $n$.

Comment: With $n=2$ : $1+3+[(2n+1)=5]=9=3^2=(2=n+1)^2$.

Comment: Both of the formulations are correct. "$2n{+}1$" a a fairly standard way of specifying an odd number.

Comment: Modified the tag to be `summation` rather than the set theory tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are right.

Take your formula:

$1+ 3+...+(2n-1) = n^2$

plug in n+1:

$1+ 3+...+(2(n+1)-1) = (n+1)^2$

which becomes

$1+ 3+...+(2n+1) = (n+1)^2$